# How to retrieve Authorization header (rails / react app)

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, jwt, fetch

Im banging my head and cant solve the mystery :(.

I've rails app and react, rails app returns `Authorization bearer token` in response header and also it returns `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Authorization`

I see in the responses that everything is returned properly, but when I try to get value of Authorization header using `response.headers.get('Authorization')` Im getting `null`

My Fetch looks like:

```
fetch('/users/sign_in.json', {
    method: 'POST', 
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-CSRF-Token': token}, 
    body: JSON.stringify({ user: values }) 
}) 
.then((response) => console.log(response.headers.get('Authorization'))) 
.then((data) => console.log(data))
```

What Im missing?

Ive checked cookies - rails does not save token into cookie, Im using devise-jwt gem. Thanks for any hint.

Comment: You can override devise sign in and return hash with token inside of it. However, this approach is not recommended

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved...

When user signs in, in first response he gets Authorization header. I've tried sign in already signed user, and I'didnt get any proper header although in chrome debugger Authorization header was present in response :/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).